# After updating bower getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bower

After running `bower update` I'm getting the below error on clicking the edit and new button.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

[image]

**Bower json**:

```
{
  "name": "my-admin",
  "authors": [
    "John"
  ],
  "description": "admnistration module",
  "main": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.2",
    "datatables.net-select-bs": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.16.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "^0.1.0-beta.9",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "^1.4.1",
    "knockout": "3.4.0",
    "knockout-mapping": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ko-reactor": "^1.3.9",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.27",
    "summernote": "^0.8.9",
    "bootstrap-wysiwyg": "*",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.15.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.37.0",
    "ndm2-ckeditor-placeholder-elements": "^1.0.3",
    "arnapou-jqcron": "arnapou/jqcron"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "knockout": "3.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

**Console error is coming from this section (cx.forms.js):**

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data){
    var $element = $(element);
    var options = allBindings.get("select2Options");
    var newData = ko.toJS(options.data);
    var oldData = $element.data("select2").options.options.data; // ERROR coming from this line
    var observedValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

    // Check if the list of options is changed and update them
    if(JSON.stringify(oldData) !== JSON.stringify(newData)){
        var dataBind = element.attributes['data-bind'].nodeValue;
        var propertyName = dataBind.match(/select2Binding\s*:\s*(?:{.*,?\s*data\s*:\s*)?([^{},\s]+)/);
        var valueName = (propertyName && propertyName.length) ? propertyName[1] : null
        // Select2 has no support for dynamically set the options, destroy and recreate
        options.data = newData;
        $element.select2("destroy").html('');
        $element.select2(options);
        // Set selected values
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(valueName))
            $(element).val(ko.unwrap(data[valueName])).trigger("change");
    }

    if(JSON.stringify($(element).select2("val")) !== JSON.stringify(observedValue))
        $(element).val(observedValue).trigger("change");
}
```

Let me know if you need more information from my side.

Comment: could you update html call select too ??

Comment: @HuaTrung I was feeding the wrong data now it's working.